# Trying to set folder name as variable

Tags: php

My index.php is stored in ***/101/index.php. What I want to do is to extract the parent folder name and use it as a $var.

I tried the `$var = getcwd() . "\n";` , but it gets the whole structure, etc: c:/wamp/www/HC/101. Is it even possible to get out only the last folder in the line?

Comment: Use `basename` php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dirname = __DIR__;
basename($dirname); //Returns the current file directory name
```

In your example ***c:/wamp/www/HC/101*** should return ***101***

Answer (score 0):

`$directory = str_replace(dirname(__DIR__), null, __DIR__):`
Or `basename(__DIR__)`

Comment: This also did it :) Thank you for your time and effort ! Appreciate it!